# Spring webflux some methods not work without subscribe or block

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

New to reactive programming and also Spring Webflux, I have a method to get value from redis and expire the key under certain conditions. But the code expire key always not work.

my current implmention:

```java
private Mono<MyObject> getMyObjectFromCache(String url) {
    RMapReactive<String, String> rMap = redissonReactiveClient.getMap(url);
    return rMap.readAllMap()
            .flatMap(m ->
                    rMap.remainTimeToLive()
                            .flatMap(ttl -> {
                                        final long renewalThreshold = 60 * 60 * 1000;
                                        if (ttl <= renewalThreshold) {
                                            System.out.println("start expiring");
                                            // it doesn't work without subscribe()
                                            rMap.expire(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
                                        }
                                        return Mono.just(JSONObject.parseObject(JSON.toJSONString(m), MyObject.class));
                                    }
                            )
            );
}
```

expire method returns `Mono<Boolean>`

```java
    public Mono<MyObject> getMyObjInfo(String url) {
        // something else
        return getMyObjectFromFromCache(url).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> getMyObjectFromRemoteService(url)));
    }
```

CustomGatewayFilter

```java
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
                ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
                ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                URI uri = request.getURI();
                
                return getMyObjInfo(uri.getPath())
                        .flatMap(api -> {
                            // something else
                            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
                        });
```

when I test the filter , only print start expiring , but it doesn't work.

if i add `subscribe` or `block`, it can work. obviously this is not a good idea, I shouldn't break the reactor chain.

please could I have a correctly way to write this?

thanks

Comment: Because you are ignoring the return `return redissonReactiveClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reactive you need to combine all async operations into a flow, chaining publishers (`Mono`/`Flux`) using various reactive operators (assembly time) and then subscribe to it (subscription time). You are right that calling `subscribe` explicitly is a bad practice and should be avoided. Spring WebFlux subscribes to the provided flow behind the scene.

In your code you are breaking the flow by not chaining `rMap.expire(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);`. You could rewrite the code like this

```
private Mono<MyObject> getMyObjectFromCache(String url) {
    RMapReactive<String, String> rMap = redissonReactiveClient.getMap(url);
    return rMap.readAllMap()
            .flatMap(m ->
                    rMap.remainTimeToLive()
                            .flatMap(ttl -> {
                                final long renewalThreshold = 60 * 60 * 1000;
                                if (ttl <= renewalThreshold) {
                                    System.out.println("start expiring");
                                    // it doesn't work without subscribe()
                                    return rMap.expire(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
                                }
                                return Mono.just(false);
                            })
                            .then(JSONObject.parseObject(JSON.toJSONString(m), MyObject.class))
            );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked indeed. And I still have two questions, why the return value is `Mono.just(false)` not `Mono.just(ttl)`, I have got value is Long type. Then if I call a method have return value in `doFinally`,its param is a consumer, no return value, what should I do to keep the reactor chain.

Comment: You could return any `Mono` even `Mono.empty()`. The idea behind `Mono.just(false)` was to have the same return type as `rMap.expire` and you could potentially extract it into a separate method `Mono<Boolean> expireIfRequired(...)`

Comment: Not sure I understood the second question but if publisher returns no `onNext` signal (e.g. `Mono.empty()`) you could use `then(...)`,  `thenReturn()` or `switchIfEmpty` to react on `onComplete` signal.